# Is there any difference in using React component as a (HTML tag)/ (JS function call)

Tags: reactjs

I have a component, something like,

```
const ComponentA = ({ heading })=> {
 return (<h1>{ heading }</h>);
};
```

Is there any difference in rendering this component using below two options,

Option 1

```
const ComponentB = ()=> {
 return ComponentA({ heading: 'Heading test' });
};
```

Option 2

```
const ComponentB = ()=> {
 return <ComponentA heading='Heading test' />;
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. There is a very important difference. In option 1, `ComponentA` is not actually a component as far as React is concerned. In option 2 it is.

The best way to illustrate the difference is to put state or another hook inside of `ComponentA`. Option 1 will not work as expected. (**Note**: if it does happen to work as expected, you still shouldn't trust it. This is where bugs can sneak in because they don't cause issues until *later*).

Here is an example where using hooks *appears* to work, but breaks after you get the counter past 5. This is because React is treating the hooks inside `ComponentA` as if they belong to `Example`. Notice how the JSX version works as expected even after it disappears.

```js
const {useState, useEffect} = React;

const ComponentA = ({ id, heading })=> {
   React.useEffect(() => {
    console.log(id, 'mounted');
   }, []);
 
 return (
    <h1>
      { heading }
    </h1>
  );
};

const Example = () => {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}>Re-render me</button> {count}
      {count < 5 ? ComponentA({ heading: 'Heading test1', id: 1 }) : null}
      {count < 3 ? <ComponentA heading='Heading test2' id={2} /> : null}
    </div>
   );
}

ReactDOM.render(<Example />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

The reason is JSX (`< />` syntax) is actually just a syntax for calling `React.createElement`. If this is not called, the function component does not get it's own lifecycle, etc. You've bypassed the way React tracks components.